# Война со строкой поиска Google! id/class элемента

Tags: javascript, java, xml, selenium-webdriver, junit

Всем привет!

пожалуй сразу покажу вам кусок кода, а после расскажу в чем проблема!

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
public void findNews() {
    webDriver.get("https://www.google.ru/");
    WebElement inputField = webDriver.findElement(By.className("gLFyf gsfi"));
    WebElement findButton = webDriver.findElement(By.className("gNO89b"));

    inputField.click();
    inputField.sendKeys("программирование");
    findButton.click();
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать запрос в поисковой строке с последующим нажатием для перехода на другую страницу !
По итогу тест рушится, потому что ему не нравится название класса для привязки к элементам (id не имеют, по крайней мере у меня не получилось найти). Ниже ошибка, которую дает терминал

**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".gLFyf\ gsfi"}
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-7UTLMAI1', ip: '192.168.54.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 85.0.4183.102, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\devs\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54693}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 3304323dcdfed0545d4f6f80f2d56308
*** Element info: {Using=class name, value=gLFyf gsfi}**

Comment: `".gLFyf\ gsfi"`... валидный селектор должен быть таким →`.gLFyf.gsfi`. А что, если убрать второй класс, оставить только `gLFyf` ? P.s. нужно именно нажатие и ввод ? Потому что результаты поиска можно получить через прямой адрес `https://www.google.ru#q=john+doe`